# django download view downloading only .xls instead of file with extension on model

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have my Django view where I upload the file from admin and users download it on the frontend when I download the file on the frontend the download is extension with only .xls i.e when I upload the file with .xlsx extension it is still downloading with .xls instead the file should be downloaded according to the extension either its xls or xlsx.

**views.py**

```
class myAPIView(APIView):

   def get(self, request):
    data = Model.objects.first()
    filename = data.file.name
    file_extention = filename.split('.')[-1] 
    response = HttpResponse(
    data.file.path,
    content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = \
        'attachment; filename="output_file"'+ file_extention
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard that you can apply(edit the content-type for you.)

```
class myAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        data = Model.objects.first()
        filename = data.file # or data.file.name based on your models.
        file_extention = filename.split('.')[-1] # something which is seprated by dot. in the last
        
        response = HttpResponse(
        file_path,
        content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = \
            'attachment; filename="output_file"'+ file_extention
        return response
```

Comment: with your code the file is downloading as output_file_xlsx and extension is after _ and not . it doesnt make the download file according to the extension i tried to change that to  filename="output_file"'+'.'+ file_extension it downloads as output_file_.xlsx but when i open the file its says invalid file

Comment: yes, becasue your data.file might not be a file but just a path to file.

Comment: In this case the view is downloading the textfile with name output_file_extension with file path inside it..

Comment: I have edited my code

Comment: Hi @Tim, are you getting any data in your text file?

Comment: no i am getting a file with no ecxtension and file path in it

Comment: i mean is the text file empty?

Comment: no it has the file path insde it

Comment: ok, got it, I ll update the answer by night(Indian Standard Time).